# How to disable adding ".self." in Sprockets 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

Even if `config.assets.digest = false` is set Sprockets 3.0 keep adding `.self.` to all static files:
`application.css` becomes `application.self.css?body=1`

How to disable adding `self`? It is needed for correct browsersync work.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it already? Running into the same problem ..

Comment: I've fixed it by downgrading Sprockets to 2.x release in gemfile.(

Comment: Does it make sense to raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues)?

Comment: It is already reported as a bug. If you need to keep 3.0, the entire page can be captured in a buffer, and the '.self' stripped out or you can copy/link the files to be file.self.ext as well

Comment: @Dimitry Answer your own question with the updated infos you have. You should not leave it unanswered.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Sprockets 3, `.self.css` is added because you have the `config.assets.debug = true` config set (not the digest config, that's unrelated).

If you add the following to your `development.rb` or `production.rb` file, it will work as you expect:

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

Comment: The thing is, this than conactenates all files into one file. Individual debugging of files in browser is no longer possible.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading sprockets worked for me. Add the following to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
```

and run

```
bundle update sprockets
```