# Sprockets adds '.self' before js or css which causes 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

So, essentially, I was on Rails 3.2.22, then I upgraded to 4.0, then to 4.1, and finally 4.2.

When I load any page, the browser console shows "something.self.js" was not found (404). Now that's true, because that filename doesn't contain .self extension.

What is the solution? Similar question was asked here [How to disable adding ".self." in Sprockets 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732377/how-to-disable-adding-self-in-sprockets-3-0) and the answer given is to turn off debug `config.assets.debug = false`.

Basically, that then concatenates all files into one big file. I really want to have the browser show separate files (that makes debugging easier for me).

So two questions really: 1) What is the wisdom behind this .self? What's the ideal use case? 2) How do I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this.

So, the file name had a plus `+` in it. It was `riot+compiler.min.js` and this kind of a file name is going to raise a 404 when its `.self.js` is going to be requested.

That maybe totally undocumented (at least I didn't search for it), but I'm putting it here so that someone in future gets help.